# Resources$NotFoundException google_play_services_version after gradle and robolectric upgrade

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric

I am attempting to update a project to Gradle 3.0.1 / gradle wrapper 4.1. Robolectric tests that used to work are now failing when run with `./gradlew testDebugUnitTest`:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: org.odk.collect.android:integer/google_play_services_version
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:72)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:319)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:220)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:108)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:35)
```

- com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1
- org.robolectric.robolectric:3.5.1
- build tools 26.0.2
- gradle wrapper 4.1

This is an open source project -- the updated configuration is available [here](https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/pull/1645/files).

It doesn't seem related but just in case -- we also started seeing `pmd` and `lint` errors that we didn't before. Those configs or versions haven't changed.

I have found the following possibly related issues:

- https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3333
- https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3374
- [Reference to findViewById() is ambiguous when running unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556249/reference-to-findviewbyid-is-ambiguous-when-running-unit-test)

None of the suggestions on those posts have helped so far. I've read the release notes for gradle and robolectric and am not seeing any hints. Any idea which tool is likely to be causing the problem? Any thing else I can try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing a `@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", packageName = "org.odk.collect")` and adding in `testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources true` did the trick. Full diff [here](https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/pull/1645/commits/1af4f521926ffc07e71b43ae90be811873755cb6).

Comment: Do you have AAPT2 disabled? I am seeing this issue only with AAPT2 disabled (even with the `includeAndroidResources true`).